# Event not firing after item updated, even after re-adding the handler

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mouseevent

In my Program Cyrus-Beck algorithm, I have to clip the points. The points inside the clipping window have to be red. The outside is still black.

I represent point in program as `rectangle` and I give the event handler for delete the point. when I wanted to delete points, points outside the window is working, but points that inside polygon didn't work, event the right-click event not call.

Here is my Point class.

*Ignore the `Component` class, because it just nothing than handler to canvas in the main window*

```
        Public Class Points
            Inherits Component

            Public items As List(Of Point) = New List(Of Point)()
            Public rects As List(Of Rectangle) = New List(Of Rectangle)


        'add element
            Public Overrides Sub Canvas1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
                canvas.Cursor = Cursors.Pen
            End Sub

            Public Overrides Sub Canvas1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
                canvas.Cursor = Cursors.Pen
                If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then
                    items.Add(e.GetPosition(canvas))

                    Dim p As Rectangle = New Rectangle()
                    p.Width = 3
                    p.Height = 3
                    canvas.SetLeft(p, e.GetPosition(canvas).X)
                    canvas.SetTop(p, e.GetPosition(canvas).Y)
                    p.Stroke = Brushes.Black
                    p.Fill = Brushes.Black
                    rects.Add(p)
                End If
            End Sub



    'deleting element
'this method not calling when the element has updated
            Sub point_rightClick(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
                Dim temp As Rectangle = New Rectangle()
                temp = DirectCast(sender, Rectangle)
                Dim pt As Point = New Point(Controls.Canvas.GetLeft(temp), Controls.Canvas.GetTop(temp))
                canvas.Children.Remove(temp)
                items.Remove(pt)
                rects.Remove(temp)
            End Sub

            Public Shared Function samePoint(one As Rectangle, two As Rectangle) As Boolean
                Return ((Controls.Canvas.GetLeft(one) = Controls.Canvas.GetLeft(two)) And (Controls.Canvas.GetTop(one) = Controls.Canvas.GetTop(two)))
            End Function

            Public Shared Function samePoint(one As Point, two As Rectangle) As Boolean
                Return (one.X = Controls.Canvas.GetLeft(two)) And (one.Y = Controls.Canvas.GetTop(two))
            End Function
        End Class
```

To able to delete, I have `deleting` that represents the status, if `deleting` is `true` and `currentState = MouseState.Pointer`. the code will add handler to all the `points` (rectangles).

```
Private Sub chge_pointer_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles chge_pointer.Click
    currentState = MouseState.Pointer
    deleting = True

    chooseHandler()

End Sub


Private Sub chooseHandler()
        If deleting Then
            For Each r As Rectangle In points.rects
                AddHandler r.MouseRightButtonDown, AddressOf points.point_rightClick
            Next
        Else
            For Each r As Rectangle In points.rects
                RemoveHandler r.MouseRightButtonDown, AddressOf points.point_rightClick
            Next
        End If

    End Sub
```

Before I modified the points to be red, I have to have a loop to check if the position is same, if the position same so edit the points

```
    Dim z As CyrusBeck = New CyrusBeck(clippingWindow)
                z.Clip(points.items)
'CyrusBeck has a properties 'points'
'CyrusBeck.points saves the all the point that inside the clipping window
                For i As Integer = 0 To points.rects.Count - 1
                    For Each p As Point In z.points
                        If CGAProject.Points.samePoint(p, points.rects.Item(i)) Then
                            Dim temp_r As Rectangle = New Rectangle()
                            temp_r = points.rects.Item(i)

                            temp_r.Stroke = Brushes.Red
                            temp_r.Fill = Brushes.Red
                            points.rects.Add(temp_r)
                            points.rects.RemoveAt(i)
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
```

when the program reaches  this, `currentState` would Never to be `MouseState.Pointer`. so if user want to delete a point, user have to be press  button `chge_pointer` so my `chge_pointer_Click` is called and all my handler would be re-setted again.

Why `Rectangle.MouseRightButtonDown` is not call when the `rectangle` has updated?
the rectangles that haven't update call the `Rectangle.MouseRightButtonDown` event, so I have re-set the handler.

What's worng?

Is there any alternative way so user can delete rectangle inside and outside the window?

**Note :**

- I have resetted the handler just after I assigned back my `Rectangle` to the list, but it still didn't work.
- I also create `AddHandler temp_r.MouseRightButtonDown, AddressOf points.point_rightClick` just after I assigned back my `Rectangle` to the list, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your events for clicking, like:

```
Sub point_rightClick(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
```

I think you should have a "handles".

E.g.

```
Sub point_rightClick(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles point.MouseClick
```

Without this, the sub will never be called (as it seems is happening).

This method also has no "handles"

```
Public Overrides Sub Canvas1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
```

and it could be:

```
Public Overrides Sub Canvas1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles Canvas1.MouseDown
```

Comment: what shoud I type? is it `handles point.MouseRightButton` ? that gives me error, undefined `point`. I think that's not the problem, because this method work for un-updated item.

Comment: @Jodivanz Without the "handles" these methods won't get called when you click the form elements. Ideally, you should handle FORMELEMENT.MouseClick, and then you can check if it is a right-click or left-click. 
What do you want to be clicked to trigger the Point_MouseClick?

Comment: @Jodivanz - You don't need `Handles` if you are using `AddHandler`.  If you do use `Handles`, then make sure your variable is declared `WithEvents`.

Comment: the event not from the the element, but from all elements inside list. please see my  `chooseHandler()` method.